# Any guide for porting legacy AddOn to newer version of Mathematica?

Tags: application, upgrade

Years ago, I purchased the Structural Mechanics Application for Mathematica.  I decided to take a look at it again, but it has not been ported to Mathematica 10.  It is only available for Mathematica 7 and 8.

The setup program won't even run on 64-bit Windows.  I was able to run the install script in an OpenSuse virtual machine to get the files extracted and placed in the file system.  I then copied the file structure back to MSW 10.

But I am not sure how to get Mathematica to see them.  I am willing to experiment with upgrading the code, but I would prefer not to re-invent the wheel.

**Is there any guide (formal or informal) for porting legacy apps and addons to more recent versions of Mathematica?**

---

Edit to add some of what I've tried.  I really don't what to approach the problem one blunder at a time.  That is why I am seeking a guide to get me started.

But, since someone asked me if I had tried addding the package to the $Path, I figured I would show some of what I've tried already.

```
smDir = FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "AddOns", "Applications", 
"StructuralMechanics"}];
DirectoryQ@smDir
```

> True

```
PrependTo[$Path, FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory
, "AddOns", "Applications", "StructuralMechanics"}]];
Needs["StructuralMechanics`"]
```

> $Failed

```
SetDirectory[
  FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "AddOns", "Applications", 
    "StructuralMechanics"}]];
FileNames["*"]
```

> {"BeamAnalysis.m", "Common.m", "Documentation", \
>   "GoverningEquations.m", "Kernel", "NumCrossSectionProperties.m", \
>   "OneDElements.m", "PlaneElasticity.m", "StressAnalysis.m", \
>   "SymCrossSectionProperties.m", "TorsionAnalysis.m", \
>   "TriangulatePolygon.m", "TwoDElements.m"}

Even if I get the Context to load, I still want to be able to use the documentation for the application.  I want to do all of this in a way that has the least impact on my existing Mathematica setup.

Comment: Two points: 1) since that add on is a Wolfram application, your best bet might be asking Wolfram Support directly; 2) quite a bit of FEM functionality is included in MMA directly nowadays: would you be able to get away with what is already included in the core language?

Comment: I'm really interested in studying the application.  It's not so much the Mathematica functionality, but the exercise of applying Mathematica to the problem domain that interests me.  I recently asked WRI to provide the bits for the package, with the understanding that it is not supported on versions later than 8.  So I'm officially on my own.  The documentation for the package is online.  So that helps.  https://reference.wolfram.com/applications/structural/IntroductiontoStructuralMechanics.html

Comment: Did you place the files on Mathematica `$Path`, so it can find them? Probably the best place is `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory,"Applications","StructuralMechanics"}]`.