# Using the obsolete structural mechanics package

Tags: packages, documentation

I wanted to use the obsolete structural mechanics package which its documentation still exists [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/applications/structural/IntroductiontoStructuralMechanics.html#:%7E:text=Structural%20Mechanics%20is%20a%20collection,in%20analyzing%20elastic%20structural%20elements.&text=In%20practice%2C%20the%20engineer%20can,other%20professional%20engineering%20analysis%20tools.) but I could not load it from the default packages of Mathematica nor do I found the installation files online.

I was wondering if anyone can guide me to install and use this package.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by `could not load it from the default packages of Mathematica`  what exactly did you type for this effect. `do I found the installation files online`   This was an application sold by WRI. I have bought this myself and have it. You can't just find it online. Did you buy this before?  Any way, it is an absolute application and will not work any more on current versions and I do not think you can even buy it any more. But you could check with customer support at WRI if you want.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175559/1871

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you want to use it for? Dependent on that there may be workarounds.

Answer (score 5):

This package never shipped with Mathematica. It was a separate product that you could buy for extra cost. This is why you will not find the files for download.

You can see a snapshot of the old product page at the internet archive.

https://web.archive.org/web/20180525200146/https://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/structural/

Comment: Where can I buy it? I did not find any store for it. @Szalbolcs

Comment: @Alex97 Contact Wolfram.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, you made me install it :).

I found it on my computer and installed it, and it actually works! (at least on the examples I tried). Here is some screen shots. At bottom I put the documentation files only in a zip file.

[image]

[image]

[image]

> Structural Mechanics is a collection of Mathematica packages that
> address computational problems in analyzing elastic structural
> elements. The design of the package uses the symbolic capability of
> Mathematica so that the package functions can be used as an
> interactive engineering "handbook". While many results are given in
> closed form, Structural Machanics incorporates some inherently
> numerical techniques, such as the finite element method,  by utilizing
> Mathematica's rich numerical facilities.
>
> The main engineering mechanics topics covered in the Structural
> Mechanics package are as follows:

1 cross-sectional properties of two-dimensional shapes

2 bending of beams

3 torsional analysis of beams

4 two-dimensional finite element analysis

5 analysis of stress at a point

6 equations of elasticity theory

Then opened Mathematica 12.3.1 and typed

```
<< StructuralMechanics`
```

Examples using it

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And so on. It has many .nb files for help. They all open OK and the commands are all there. I put these notebooks in a zip file (I think it is OK just to share the documentation only?).

Here is the zip file [structural_mechanics_1_0_documentaion.zip](https://12000.org/tmp/structural_mechanics_1_0_docs/structural_mechanics_1_0_documentaion.zip)

Comment: Is there any alternative for this package?

Comment: @Alex97 I do not know of one offhand. I do not do much in this area anymore myself. But may be if you google around you could find something. I think if you find textbook on the subject which uses Mathematica, it might have something related in it.